# Generic Type with dynamic count of type parameters

Tags: c#, generics

How do i can define a type **List** so that i could use it as:

```
var l1 = new List<int>();
var l2 = new List<int, long>();
var l3 = new List<int, long, byte>();
```

?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is unclear. The reason there is no List<T, T1, T2, ...> in .NET is that it's useless. You can just create a type that wraps int long and byte and make a list of that type.

Comment: What is your use case? You should explain us what you want to do.

Comment: The one thing that i try to archive is have List type, that can be created with different count of type parameters. In my realization it need to map some of types to List(instead of pass them to any method).

Comment: @devi How would you expect to populate a `List<int, long>` list? What do you want such a list to contain? int? long? Some sort of structure that contains two fields (int and long)?

Comment: That list populates from source, which can contain different types of items. List needs to know a set of available types to map source item. As example List can return IEnumerable<Item>, but source contains Item, Announcement and Task with different fields each. By that approach List can define types, which it can contain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list of tuples:

```
var l1 = new List<int>();
var l2 = new List<Tuple<int, long>>();
var l3 = new List<Tuple<int, long, byte>>();
```

Comment: eventually inherit the Tuple class to make more concrete classes

Comment: `Tuple` is a good idea, but I think it should be mentioned that it requires .Net 4.0.

Comment: Use tuples not so clear as direct enumeration of types, but good idea. It have any analog in .net 3.5 ?

Comment: Not in the BCLs, but it is very straightforward to implement yourself.

Comment: My realization of List is so like to Tuple

Answer (score 1):

Say you wanted to get the 3rd item from your `l3` list - what would you do?

If your answer is "I'd cast it to `long`, since `int` and `byte` are both castable to `long` anyway", you should use a `List<long>` in the first place.

If you are going to use `l3[3].GetType()` and `if else` on the retrieved type, you should consider using a `List<object>`, as you're treating items as "of unknown type".

Answer (score 0):

So, i found a solution. It needs to define base type List:

```
 class List    {  }
```

And inherit a number of childs from it:

```
class List<T>    {  }

class List<T, T1> : List<T> { }

class List<T, T1, T2> : List<T> { }
```

(Inheritance is not necessarily, but it needs if List been castable to List )

Base List constructor can get all applied generic parameters:

```
class List
{
    Type[] _types;

    public List()
    {
        _types = GetType().GetGenericArguments();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Just" inheriting List<T> is going to screw with you. You're gonna have to either override every member so that both collections get updated, or define an **explicit** operator that converters from one to the other. I Stress explicit because there is a loss of information (what happens for T1 and T2 when you cast to List<T> ?)

Comment: But that's still just a `List<T>` in the end. i.e. you will only be able to add and remove instances of type `T`, not `T1` and `T2`. Or are you trying to accomplish something else?

Comment: The one thing that i try to archive is have List type, that can be created with different count of type parameters. In my realization it need to map some of types to List(instead of pass them to any method). Base constructor gets generic parameters and save them to a Type[] array